# Добавить пробелы перед словом равные длины слов

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Дана строка, содержащая слова, разделенные одиночными пробелами. Сформировать строку, в которой количество пробелов перед каждым словом будет равно его длине. Надо написать код используя регулярные выражения.

Есть такой код но метод Regex там не используется.

```
var str = "longstring one two three"
    .Split(' ', (char)StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(x => new string(' ', x.Length) + x)
    .Aggregate((x, y) => x + y);
            Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Answer (score 2):

Пишу код просто оптимальнее и без регулярок т.к. не понимаю куда регулярки сюда вообще можно прикрутить

```
var str = "longstring one two three"
    .Split()
    .Select( a => (new string(' ', a.Length)) + a );
        
Console.WriteLine(String.Join("", str));
```